# Recieving string from network fills console with newlines?

Tags: c#, networking, chat

I have been working on a little chat system that involves rooms. Everything on the server as far as I know is working fine. I know the code for the client I'm using is fine too because I can't replicate this on a Windows Forms app.

Here's a little GIF as a demonstration of what happens when I do this.
(Left = server, right = client)
[Demonstration of what happens when the client receives a message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbWHt.gif)

I know nothing is wrong with the server since output is fine on that side, so here's what possibly is the offending code on the client side:

This is what happens when a message is received:

```
while (clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            int buffSize = 0;
            byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            buffSize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            readData = "" + returndata;
            Console.WriteLine(readData);
        }
```

And here's the code when I send it. Note that I do a little bit of sanitation:

```
string inps = Console.In.ReadLine().Trim();
inps = Regex.Replace(inps, @"[^\u0009^\u000A^\u000D^\u0020-\u007E]", "");

byte[] outs = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inps + "$"); //$ being used as a end of message is only temporary
serverStream.Write(outs, 0, outs.Length);
serverStream.Flush();
```

I'm not sure about you but I see nothing wrong with this code, personally I'm lost for words here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So `returndata` is coming back empty and you are simply writing new lines to your `Console` via the `WriteLine` method?

Comment: Are you asking why you are not getting any data on the receive end? Or why your console is filling up with new lines?

Comment: Maybe, but not exactly sure about that. I did have a simular problem with buffers a while ago where it printed 0x0 but I'm not sure if it's related to that. And no, I'm not asking why I'm not getting any data. I'm recieving data, but it possibly contains newlines.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` will end everything with a line terminator, so presuming you have no actual data coming through your stream, it would make sense that your console is filled with empty lines.. can you put a breakpoint on your receive and verify if you're actually getting any data?

Comment: Think of everything you pass to `Console.WriteLine` as automatically appended with `"\r\n"`

Comment: Yeah, I'll try that, just give me a few seconds

Comment: You should be able to check the `DataAvailable` property of the stream to see if there is anything that you can read from it, rather than just calling `Read`

Comment: From what I'm seeing in the debugger its my message then its appended with an unknown amount of \0.

Comment: so `returndata` starts out with the message you're expecting, then followed by a number of null terminators?

Comment: [Couldn't be more right.](http://i.imgur.com/ygMKqvr.png)

Comment: Hmm.. wheres the `$` that you put in as terminator?

Comment: It doesn't get sent back to the client. And you'll have to wait a few minutes before my next response, going to eat.

Comment: Alright.. and `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize` on receive side matches `outs.Length` on the send side?

Comment: Took a further look in the debugger and outs.length is 6 but the ReceiveBufferSize is 65536.

Comment: _readData = "" + returndata.Substring(returndata.IndexOf('\0'));_

Comment: What makes me confused is that if the server sends "<hello>hello" which is 12 characters, and I can confirm it is because the byte table length is 11 but my question is how does that get transformed into 65536 bytes with a whole bunch of nulls? According to the server we sent 12 bytes, but to the client its 65536 bytes but ~65528 bytes are null.

@Steve thats more of a workaround then a pure fix

Comment: What is the value of _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize_ ?

Comment: @Steve 65536 but like it said 99% of it is null. when I send a message with the nick "hello" and the message "hello" it would return like this: "<hello>hello\0\0\0\0\0\0..." but with \0 65528 times

Comment: It seems that ASCII.GetString with a stream as input doesn't trim away the unused part of the buffer. Usually a \0 means _end of string_ but....

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your state, what is the type of the variable _clientSocket_ ?

Comment: Thats what I mean. The client cant determine the ReceiveBufferSize although the server is only sending 12 bytes. What makes me even more confused is that it can send properly but it can't receive properly, but the server can (which lead me to determine that the server wasn't the problem, I even verified this) which lead me its something to do with the client because both of them can send properly, the server can recieve properly but the client can't.

Comment: And since you mentioned, the type of clientSocket is a TCPSocket. On the server its a TCPListener on 127.0.0.1:7777 and the client socket there is a default TCPSocket.